# In PyQT how to store data emitted from signal in QRunnable

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a process that takes awhile in a PyQT4 application using Python3.  So I have been investigating using threading to speed it up.  The data can easily be broken part and processed in a loop.  I am using a custom `QRunnable` where you can pass a target function and args which is then fed into a `QThreadpool`.   I use a `pyqtSignal` to emit the processed data from each worker.  The Data is being received by my slot but it isn't being stored.  Below is an cut down example of what I have attempted.

```
import sys, time
from random import uniform
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class AWorker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    """ Generic Task for ThreadPool to execute required Kwargs =
    target (<function>): function to call
    args  (tuple): args for target
    kwargs (dict): kwargs for target """  
    def __init__(self, target=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        super(AWorker, self).__init__()
        self.target = target 
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def run(self):
        self.target(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

class myTest(QtCore.QObject):  

    doneSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)  #Create a signal to emit the data

    def __init__(self):
        super(myTest, self).__init__()        
        self._procData = [] #Place to Store data .. maybe        
        self.pool = QtCore.QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(4) #Use up to 8 threads

    def runAll(self):
        self.doneSignal.connect(self.storeData) 
        for data in range(4):
            worker = AWorker(target=self.processData, args=(data,))
            self.pool.start(worker)    

    def processData(self,data):        
        print('Crunching ...', str(data))
        outData = data+10
        time.sleep(uniform(1,3))  #Simulate this taking a random amount of time
        self.doneSignal.emit(outData)

    def storeData(self,data):        
        print('Received ...', str(data))
        self._procData.append(data)

    def getData(self):
        return self._procData

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = myTest()
    test.runAll()
    test.pool.waitForDone()
    print('All done ... and the data is: ',test.getData())
    app.exec_()
```

It runs and from the print outs the following:

```
Crunching ... 0
Crunching ... 1
Crunching ... 3
Crunching ... 2
All done ... and the data is:  []
Received ... 13
Received ... 11
Received ... 12
Received ... 10
```

Ok, so the signals aren't emitted until after they all finish? maybe?  or I can't assign to `_procData` since I am in a different thread or something? I tried removing the `waitForDone()` just to see but that as expected didn't help.

So what is the proper way to assemble the data output from each worker?  And I suppose a follow up question, how do you ensure it is put back in the correct order.

Comment: Appears to me that QThreadPool.waitForDone is not actually waiting.  You can see that the received is printing after the all done.  Additionally if you print out `_procData` on each `storeData` call, you can see that it is in fact storing the data. eg `Received ... 10 [13, 11, 12, 10]`

Comment: I see what you mean.  However, I am still not sure if waitForDone is not working or if it is blocking the signals until after wait for done completes.  Either one would give the same behavior I think.  If you comment out the wait for done line you get a different order of the print outs with some "Received"s intermixed with "Crunchings" but the All done line is still blank.  IF waitForDone wasn't doing anything then I would expect the same output either way.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue (which can also be related to this question : [Emitting signals from a QRunnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786149/emitting-signals-from-a-qrunnable)) with one of my code.
As in your case, the action in the `QRunnable` was executed but results weren't appended in the result list. The answer in the other post says it's because the main event loop isn't called (with something like `app.exec_()`). I guess in your case it's because you try to print the returned result (which is empty) before calling `app.exec_()` (I might have read that events/signals from QThread or QRunnable are queued or something like that before the `exec_` call ? Even if in your case as in mine, each individually result received could be printed from the callback function).

I guess a work-around could be to create a `QEventLoop` which will `processEvents` from the worker of the `QThreadPool`, then when it `exit()` all signals/events have been processed. Using your code it could look like :

```
def runAll(self):
    self.eventloop = QEventLoop()
    self.pool = QtCore.QThreadPool.globalInstance()
    self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(4)
    self.doneSignal.connect(self.storeData) 
    for data in range(4):
        worker = AWorker(target=self.processData, args=(data,))
        self.pool.start(worker)
    self.pool.waitForDone()
    self.eventloop.processEvents() 
    self.eventloop.exit()
    # Now your data should have been appended to your list
```

(I did not tested this snippet of code but I successfully use a similar pattern for some of my `QThreadPool`)